# How to return a javascript set style property to CSS default

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm trying to work out how, after changing style properties with javascript, I can revert to the value in the stylesheet (including the units).

In the example below, I'd like the output to read `100px` (the value in the CSS), rather than `10px`, as `getComputedStyle` gives.

I'd also keep the dummy div at `top:25px`, so removing the `style` property won't work.

The best I have is cloning the node and reading the height and storing in a property (http://jsfiddle.net/daneastwell/zHMvh/4/), but this is not really getting the browser's default css value (especially if this is set in `em`s).

http://jsfiddle.net/daneastwell/zHMvh/1/

```
<style>
 #elem-container{
   position: absolute;
   left:     100px;
   top:      200px;
   height:   100px;
 }
</style>

<div id="elem-container">dummy</div>
<div id="output"></div>  

<script>
  function getTheStyle(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("elem-container");
    elem.style.left = "10px";
    elem.style.top = "25px";
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("left");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = theCSSprop;
   }
  getTheStyle();
</script>
```

Comment: Why can't you use CSS classes? Then you'll simply add/remove them instead of changing individual style properties.

Comment: Moreover actually the current value for left _is_ 10px because getComputerStyle returns the...computed style of that element (including style attribute) and not only the rules specified in the CSS. Note: be aware that getComputedStyle isn't supported on older versions of IE.

Comment: I'm performing a task on resize, so the 'left' value is calculated, so a class wouldn't help, sorry for not having been more specific.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just clear the inline style you wish to fallback to original stylesheet on.

```
elem.style.left = null;
```

Comment: Exactly what's required, to revert the style back to the CSS value.

Comment: I would set it to `''` (empty string) to be consistent with the return value given by JavaScript.

Comment: Using `''` also makes it compatible with TypeScript.

Answer (score 7):

The [style object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) has a built-in `removeProperty()` method, so you could do something like:

```
elem.style.removeProperty('left');
```

As far as I know, this will have exactly the same effect as setting the property to `null`, as [abaelter suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699088/2759272). I just thought it might be worth including for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Looks good - seems it's IE9 up in terms of support http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t45.

Answer (score 2):

Combining abaelter's answer and http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/ gives us the below function:

```
var getCssStyle = function(elementId, cssProperty) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var inlineCssValue = elem.style[cssProperty];

  // If the inline style exists remove it, so we have access to the original CSS
  if (inlineCssValue !== "") {
    elem.style[cssProperty] = null;
  }

  var cssValue = "";
  // For most browsers
  if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    cssValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, "").getPropertyValue(cssProperty);
  }
  // For IE except 5
  else if (elem.currentStyle){
    cssProperty = cssProperty.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1) {
      return p1.toUpperCase();
    });
    cssValue = elem.currentStyle[cssProperty];
  }

  // Put the inline style back if it had one originally
  if (inlineCssValue !== "") {
    elem.style[cssProperty] = inlineCssValue;
  }

  return cssValue;
}
```

Placing in your example code and testing:

```
console.log("getCssStyle: " + getCssStyle("elem-container", "left"));
```

Gives us `getCssStyle: 100px` allowing you to see the original CSS value. If you just want to revert the value then do as abaelter says and `null` the CSS value you want to revert.

Comment: Great, this would be useful if you needed to know the value in the CSS only without altering the state of the element. As I need to revert to the CSS value, @abaelter's response is the one I'll use.

Comment: Yep I realised that after I wrote the function, but thought it might be useful.